# How to capture a repeating pattern with a condition?

Tags: java, regex

I have many Strings, e.g.:

1. `"book = 12 AND x2 = 50 AND cost = 45"`
2. `"pen = 1 AND case = 10 AND bala = 40"`
3. `...`

And I need to get `book` , `x2`, `cost`.
And  `pen` , `case`, `bala`

I use this, but it doesn't work:

```
(?:(.*?)(?==))+
```

I do not need values after '='; I need names before '='.

Comment: I am assuming there can be more than three matches, right?

Comment: Yes, my string my be "a= 10 And b=20" I need catch a and b . no catch  10 or 20

Comment: Oh Yes. very tanks. can explain how it works.

Comment: Use [`\w+(?=\s*=)`](https://regex101.com/r/uaaFid/3) if all the matches consist of only word chars.

Comment: @AliBagheri Use Wiktor's solution, it's simpler.

Comment: 'UnbearableLightness' whats delete your answer???

Comment: Been a long day, my pattern is not very efficient. Try the solution below.

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
\w+(?=\s*=)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uaaFid/3)

**Details**

- `\w+` - 1 or more letters, digits or `_` (to only match letters and digits, use `\p{Alnum}`)
- `(?=\s*=)` - that are followed with 0+ whitespaces and then a `=` char (as `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead that requires its pattern to match immediately to the right of the current location).

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/bWqU7u):

```
String s = "book = 12 AND x2 = 50";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+(?=\\s*=)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    res.add(matcher.group(0)); 
} 
System.out.println(res); 
// => [book, x2]
```

Comment: Tanks, this is my answer.and useful.

Comment: @AliBagheri If the solution works for you please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture them all using only one line of code:

```
String [] cols = str.split("\\s*=.*?(?=$|\\w+\\s*=)");
```

Rather than match the column names, this split regex matches *between* the column names.

---

Test code:

```
String str = "book = 12 AND x2 = 50 AND cost = 45";
String[] cols = str.split("\\s*=.*?(?=$|\\w+\\s*=)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cols));
```

Output:

```
[book, x2, cost]
```